# can't set objective-c property from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

in the header file of an objective-c code there is an integer property

```
@property int xmBufferSize;
```

I am trying to set property from swift code by

```
let sharedExample: AnyObject! = XMPAudioPlayer.instance()

sharedExample.xmBufferSize = 1024
```

Error I get is

**Cannot assign to 'xmBufferSize' in 'sharedExample'**

This must be pretty straight forward why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend removing the `AnyObject!` annotation and leave the compilator to infer the type to be correct - `XMPAudioPlayer`. Then you will have the correct type and set the attribute as usual.

Like this:

```
let sharedExample = XMPAudioPlayer.instance()
sharedExample.xmBufferSize = 1024
```

In case your `instance()` method returns `AnyObject`, which would be highly unfortunate, then I'd recommend casting it like this:

```
let sharedExample = XMPAudioPlayer.instance() as! XMPAudioPlayer
sharedExample.xmBufferSize = 1024
```

Comment: `Constant 'sharedExample' inferred to have type 'AnyObject!', which may be unexpected`

Comment: The problem is you also leave the next developer to infer the type and they are not as good as the compiler at that. If the initial developer can't even figure out the type where does that leave the next developer?

Comment: In that case, the second solution is always an option.

Answer (score 1):

Since `AnyObject` does not have the property `xmBufferSize`, the error occurs. Therefore, you should first cast `shareExample` to appropriate type.

(e.g., `(sharedExample as! YourAwesomeClass).xmBufferSize = 1024`)

If you want to set property without type casting, try

`sharedExample.setValue(1024, forKey: "xmBufferSize")`

It's not typesafe way, but sometimes it's convenient and useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your `XMPAudioPlayer` interface, the return type of the `instance` method is `id`, correct? Change the return type to `instancetype` and the compiler will correctly infer its type, and the error will be resolved.